# Wrap items in WrapPanel in pairs

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF ListBox that uses a WrapPanel as its ItemsPanel with a Horizontal orientation that displays an ObservableCollection of Items.

An Item can either be a Box or a Separator.

A Box is always followed by a Separator in the collection, i.e. like this: Box, Separator, Box, Separator, Box, Separator, etc.

This is illustrated visually here:

[image]

Users are able to resize the width of the WrapPanel - and here comes the problem: If the user resizes the width to some certain "unlucky" positions, then the WrapPanel wraps in an undesired way, i.e. like this:

[image]

I would like such that each 'Box & Separator' pair always wrap together, i.e. like this:

[image]

What is the easiest way to achieve a wrapping behavior such that 'Box & Separator' pairs wrap together? Do I have to roll my own WrapPanel?

Here are sample classes and ViewModel:

```
public abstract class Item
{

}

public class Box : Item
{

}

public class Separator : Item
{

}

public class ViewModel
{
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Box(),
            new Separator(),
            new Box(),
            new Separator(),
            new Box(),
            new Separator()
        };

}
```

And sample XAML bound to the ViewModel:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Box}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="50" Width="50" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Separator}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="50" Width="10" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

NB: I know that I could just have Separators rendered visually as part of the DataTemplate for Boxes. However, if possible I would like to keep them as separate objects as they have some selection behavior with ContextMenus and such.

Comment: any source code ?

Comment: Yup added sample code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just contain your two controls (rectangle and seperator) in a grid or stackpanel this should do the trick for you and keep them from seperating:

```
    <WrapPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="HotPink" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            <Separator Height="100" Width="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="HotPink" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            <Separator Height="100" Width="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, but then they are not individually selectable if I put them in the same DataTemplate. I've added sample code to the question to better describe the situation :)

Comment: Create a custom control that contains both the box and seperator or do it with a style